# Where are vents required for bathroom drains?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, drain-waste-vent, sewer

[image: drains] Here is a diagram of the new drain plumbing we are installing for one and a half new bathrooms.

Where should I locate any required vents on these lines?
I live in Oakland County, MI and it looks they allow the use of air admittance vents for plumbing fixture vents (searched [this document](https://archive.org/stream/gov.mi.plumbing/mi_plumbing_djvu.txt)). Would using an AAV be a reasonable option for any required vents?